# Какой метод использовать для получения cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookie, chrome-extension

Я делаю свое собственное расширение Chrome на JS, поэтому, мне нaдo получать куки с нужного сайта. Но я не знаю, какой метод мне использовать.

Какой метод использовать для этого?

Comment: Вопрос, вероятно, будет закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метода [`chrome.cookies.getAll`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-getAll) можно получить куки, соответствующие заданным параметрам, или все, если передать пустой объект.

Естественно, надо не забыть указать соответствующий permission в манифесте.

Comment: А как запросить куки именно с нужного сайта? Есть такая возможность?

Comment: Есть. Там же параметры перечислены.